# How to install bluez5.47?

Tags: bluez

When I build and install bluez 5.47, on restart, the same bluetooth 5.37 daemon starts. How to switch to the newly built 5.47?

Comment: How did you build and install the newer version? Sounds like you may have the old version still installed...

Comment: PPA here: https://launchpad.net/~bluetooth/+archive/ubuntu/bluez

Comment: ./configure, make, sudo make install as directed. Seemed to complete properly yet I still have blutoothd -v yields 5.37. Baffled.

Comment: Perhaps uninstall all bluetooth packages and then reinstall bluetooth 5.47. Easier installation and possible removal of 5.47 using `checkinstall`...